# React meteor - setup state based on props

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I'm developing a React + Meteor app.

I have a route that accepts a parameter for example to show the single page of a document, so the route accepts an ID parameter. Then the route forwards the request to:

createContainer component that gets the data from collection (based on id) and return the document to a child component

child component displays data

Now, in my child component, I want to setup state in the constructor based on the value from the data (document), but the value of the data is stil undefined in the constructor, is this normal (still loading)? How can I setup state based on value of data?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's normal.

You need to look at [componentWillReceiveProps()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops). Compare `nextProps` with `this.props` and set the state.

Comment: Thanks, it's indeed what I needed; Very useful to work with the container pattern between react/meteor.